# Synonym for "no-brainer" to describe that it's an easy decision to buy a certain product

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word like "no-brainer" (but that word seems too clunky to me).

I'll use it in a situation like this:

> The normal price for this product is $5k, but since we *really* want
>   you to have this, we made it a **no-brainer**. One single payment of
>   $1k.

"Cinch" and "cakewalk" don't quite feel right either.

The closest other term I could think of was "**slam dunk**", but that feels a little bit clunky and informal too.

What is a *professional-sounding* word or short phrase I could use to indicate that this decision is *so easy to make* because the details favor the buyer?

Comment: Are you looking for something professional-sounding?

Comment: @Spencer I'd prefer it, yes.

Comment: how about plain 'easy'?

Comment: "...but since we really want you to have this, we've made it *more advantageous*, and will charge only $1,000".

Answer (score 1):

*"...but since we really want you to have this, we made it **irresistible**."*

(Too strong, weighty, or fascinating to be resisted (OED))

Answer (score 1):

The normal price for this product is $5k, but since we really want you to have this, we made it an **easy** decision . One single payment of $1k.

**Easy decision** synonyms. Top synonym for easy decision (other word for easy decision) is **no-brainer**.[power-thesaurus](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/easy_decision)